# I am trying to run a two cluster node on hadoop 0.9.8

Tags: hadoop

Master is DUT5 and Slave is DUT4..

I am trying to run a two cluster node on hadoop 0.9.8. While running `start-dfs`, it is showing fatal error:

> [root@dut5 bin]# ./start-dfs.sh
> starting namenode, logging to /hadoop-rdma-0.9.8/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-namenode-dut5.out
> dut5: ssh: relocation error: /lib64/libkrb5.so.3: symbol k5_path_join, version krb5support_0_MIT not defined in file libkrb5support.so.0 with link time reference
> dut4: datanode running as process 11910. Stop it first.
> dut5: ssh: relocation error: /lib64/libkrb5.so.3: symbol k5_path_join, version krb5support_0_MIT not defined in file libkrb5support.so.0 with link time reference

and hadoop log shows

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000335ba4812c, pid=4368, tid=140618348889856
> Problematic frame:
> dut5: # C  [libc.so.6+0x4812c]  _IO_vfprintf+0x3e5c

---

#### Solved

The problem was with the configuration file.. disabling roce made hadoop working

Comment: Log says: datanode running as process 11910. Stop it first.

    kill -9 11910

Comment: No process running like that